# Filter api model properties by user permission level in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

We want to filter / hide / clear specific api model properties based on the user permission level.
The model itself will not differ. Just no return for those.

I found a lot of different ideas online:

- switch(userrole) and call different logic methods
- pass user role to logic
- reflection to clear properties in the response (I hate this idea)
- middleware to redirect the user to different actions

What is the recommended way to filter api model properties for specific roles?

Comment: Create view models with properties needed (for each user role) and return that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give any real specifics with what you've provided, but generally, I'd say this should go into your mapping logic. Utilize view models/DTOs to accept data from client requests. Then map that data from the view model/DTO to your entity instance. During this process, you can make decisions based on the user's role/permission set about what properties should or should not be mapped over. All of this logic can be factored out into a separate class or library of classes. Ultimately it doesn't really matter what the client *sends*. You can't control that anyway. You just need to ensure that they ultimately can't set any properties they don't have "access" to, and mapping logic is a great place for that.